# python send a list to an function( *arg)

Tags: python, list, function, arguments

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class imported_feature():
    def function_print(self, *recordList):
        """Print the first three argument of the list"""
        for i in range(3):
            print(recordList[i])
```

and I want to call the function with something that looks like this:

```
imported_feature.function_print([columns_to_add[x][j] for x in columns_to_add.keys()])
```

In columns_to_add I have all the objects that I want to give the function_print(). I iterate the function with "j" (I want to send the "j" element of each key to function_print)

I know how to solve it while making changes in function_print() (change recordList[i] to recordList[0][i]) but I wan't another solution where I change the input to be recognized as multiple objects instead of just one object?

I have tried to do:

```
list =[columns_to_add[x][j] for x in columns_to_add.keys()]
imported_feature.function_print(str(list)[1:-1])
```

But that didn't do it, any other tips on how I can unpack the keys in columns_to_add and insert the?

Comment: Why did you declare `recordList` as a star argument?

Comment: Just to clarify, if `columns_to_add` is a `dict`, instead of iterating over the keys just to grab the `j` value, why not `myList = [val[j] for val in columns_to_add.values()]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `*` again:

```
lst = [columns_to_add[x][j] for x in columns_to_add.keys()]
imported_feature.function_print(*lst[1:-1])
```

(I don't recommend using keywords as variable names)

Answer (score 1):

Just unpack it as you would with [any other function](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

```
func(*[...])
```